# How to deal with toenails that grow outwards?

Tags: health, hygiene

My 16 month old daughter has weird toenails on her big toes. They grow normally up to the point where the nails leave the nail bed, then where you would normally have the nail continue on flat for a couple of mm, instead they bend outwards/upwards. Hard to describe! They've been like that her whole life. It's only the big toes that are like this - her other toenails are normal.

I keep them trimmed as neatly as I can but it seems odd. Googling throws up things like iron deficiency, B12 deficiency, and fungal infections, but as far as I know none of those apply. I suspect it's just the way her toenails are... but how best to keep them neat and tidy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some nails are just like this. If so, you will just have to keep them trimmed well to prevent scratching.

However, a fungal infection is very possible. Cloudy nails, spotted nails, discolored nail, thick nails, tent nails and curled nails are all common symptoms. But you don't need more than one symptom to be the problem. In fact, you could be completely symptomless and still have a fungal infection. Talk to your doctor.